# rails i18n association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations, rails-i18n

I have a question regarding to i18n in rails when meeting assciations

```
class User
  belongs_to :billing_address, :class_name => "Address'
  belongs_to :delivery_address, :class_name => "Address'
end

en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        billing_address_id: "billing address"
        delivery_address_id: "delivery address"
```

the above code works, but i wonder if there is another way to achieve this by not using `_id` suffix in the yml?

Answer (score 0):

You are heading in the right direction. This would be a bit better:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      address: 'Address'
      user: 'User'
    attributes:
      address:
        city: 'City'
        zip_code: 'ZIP code'
      user:
        address_id: 'Address ID'
```

Have a look at http://xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/i18n_mehrsprachige_rails_applikation.html

Comment: address_id is for a select field, and the label should be just 'address', any more elegant way to replace `address_id: 'address'`?

Comment: That's what the models part is for. There you find 'Address'. Please read http://xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/i18n_mehrsprachige_rails_applikation.html

Comment: sorry, your answer is not really what i am looking for, but thanks for the reply